# Compositing multiple image files with one text file

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to composite multiple background images with one text file using ImageMagick.

For example:

I have these background files:

```
bg/red.png
bg/yellow.png
bg/blue.png
bg/black.png
```

and this image text files (the background is transparent):

```
txt/hello.png
```

Now, I want to composite backgrounds with `hello.png` file. Output is like:

```
output/hello_red.png
output/hello_yellow.png
output/hello_blue.png
output/hello_black.png
```

**I don't want to use loops, I just want to use one command.**

Comment: So what have you tried? Have you gotten any results that were close to working?

Comment: @Mokubai I have no other idea but to run a command for each file.